# What's the meaning of "twins in a perambulator got out of our line of fire?"

Tags: meaning

> “Now, let's come on! This time next week I shall be taking my
> holiday.” “What links?” I asked carelessly, **while twins in a
> perambulator got out of our line of fire.** “A potty little nine-hole
> affair at a hydro in the Midlands. My cousins stay there. Always will.
> Not but what the fourth and the seventh holes take some doing. You
> could manage it, though,” he said encouragingly. “You're doing much
> better. It's only your approach shots that are weak.”

-***The House Surgeon** by Rudyard Kipling.*

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2381/2381-h/2381-h.htm#link2H_4_0016

I don't understand the meaning of "while twins in a perambulator got out of our line of fire" in the passage above.

Comment: to get out of a line of fire: to avoid being hit by something.

Comment: What part of it do you not understand? Do you know what all those words mean? Do you know what a "line of fire" is? We expect you do to some basic research yourself before asking questions, and tell us in the question what you found online, and why it doesn't satisfy your question. So I'm closing this question. Please request it to be reopened once you've improved it

Answer (score 3):

> [**line of fire**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/line_of_fire), noun
>
> 1. (*military, weaponry*) direction in which a weapon fires
> 2. (*figuratively, by extension*) position vulnerable to attack

From context a few paragraphs earlier, the characters are playing golf, so "line of fire" refers to the area where they are hitting the balls.

> [**perambulator**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perambulator#English), noun
>
> 1. (*Britain*) A baby carriage; a pram.

So the twins are in a carriage. Presumably they did not move *themselves* into the line of fire; rather the pram was pushed along by an unmentioned caretaker.

Comment: Randomhead, thank you so much. your answer is very helpful.